# no content provider error when trying to fetch and display the pdf file from api

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, pdf

**I am trying to display pdf files within the app by fetching them from json api.The below is the json response of the api**

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "_id": "1230",
    "name": "multithreading",
    "pdf": "https://fileupload99.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/33d969c4-34cc-4fc0-8e55-ad2094e16db7.pdf",
    "image": "https://fileupload99.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/4e3ab24b-648c-4781-a225-3f2ad2e03f6d.png",
    "__v": 0
}
```

}

**The below is the code which I had used to convert the string into uri and then display into pdfview**

```
val pdfUrl=bookJsonObject.getString("pdf")
                val uri=Uri.parse(pdfUrl)
                pdfView.fromUri(uri).load()
```

**E/PDFView: load pdf error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://fileupload99.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/33d969c4-34cc-4fc0-8e55-ad2094e16db7.pdf This is what I found in logcat .I am using implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1' dependancy.please help me to fix this**

Comment: Apparently pdf viewer cannot load from web. Not from https urls.

Comment: @blackapps so what should I do sir

Comment: @blackapps is there any other way but I have to fetch and diaplay from net only

Comment: Download the file to device storage. Then use FileProvider.getUriForFile to get a content scheme uri.

Comment: @blackapps sir I cant download because as per my project I have to display inside the app only rather than downloading

Comment: @blackapps is there any way to get pdf file without http protocol sir

Comment: Then ask the developers of that library to implement https urls.

Comment: "I cant download" -- you do not have much of a choice. PDF viewers need the PDF file, whether those PDF viewers are part of your app or are third-party apps that you start. PDF is not a file format designed for streaming.

Comment: @CommonsWare sir google classroom displays pdf file without downnloading it into our device na sir

Comment: @blackapps sir if the pdf file is of https then it will load a sir

Comment: A Google server can "download" the PDF to itself, convert pages into images, and serve the pages as images to clients. This is how the Google Docs Web app handles PDFs, for example. Do not assume that you know the implementation of an app just by looking at the user-visible behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any solution for this problem sir

Comment: @blackapps can I try to load pdf using webview sir will it work?

Comment: @CommonsWare can I try to load a pdf using webview sir will it work?

Comment: A `WebView` has no built-in ability to display a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the pdf as a stream with a network request and then use the stream object to show the pdf:

```
    private fun setPDF() {
        CoroutineScope(Job()).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val pdfUrl = "<some url>"
            val url = URL(pdfUrl)
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
                val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(connection.inputStream)
                lifecycleScope.launch{
                    binding.pdfView.fromStream(inputStream)
                        .load()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```